# Formatting international phone numbers always start with one 0?

Tags: android, validation, verification, phone-number

A user needs to enter his/her phone number in my mobile application so I can send a text message for verification. I've a database with all country codes, so if a user says he or she is from the Netherlands it will automatically fill the prefix with `+31` (a plus sign so the exit code will be recognised automatically).

And, when a user fills in his/her phone number like `0622277333`, I need to remove the `0` prefix in case of a Dutch number so you will get `+31622277333` and not `+310622277333`.

**And thus my question:**
Is this the same for all country numbers? Can I just remove all starting zeros? Or can phone numbers start with let's say `008`, where I just need to remove one zero? Or can it start with another number sometimes? Like `1`?

I'm asking it here, cause I'm convinced some other programmer has done this before. And maybe has a regex example as well, in case it's more complicated. I wasn't able to find an answer on the internet so far.

Comment: It is probably safer to show the country code prefilled (like +31 _____) so that the user enters the phone number in the correct format.

Comment: Hi Henry, yes that's the idea. But in case an user still makes the mistake by entering his/her full mobile number, I want to validate it before sending the text message. Like I said, in case of a dutch mobile number, you need to remove the leading zero when using a country code.

Comment: This may be interesting http://www.howtocallabroad.com/codes.html (see column trunk codes)

Comment: Ah thanks! That was the answer I was looking for! I found that webpage before, but I wasn't aware of the trunk codes.